# Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 trying to create content that aligns top and bottom of row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 alpha 6

see here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment

I just found this as well:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#direction

but no luck so far

I try to:

align elements to the top *and* bottom of a row

it doesn't need to be in the same row. But I think that is the easiest. As each row is a new flex container, I don't think it works differently.

see this codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEzBrw

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

.my-top {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.my-bot {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col my-top">
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col my-bot  align-self-end">
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      grey stuff in between. no hard coding with padding or such allowed
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

desired output

[image]

Comment: Where's the code that is attempting to align elements to the bottom? So far the code only highlighting elements.

Comment: the idea was `justify-content-between` to add the space between the elements. Yeah but good question, where is the code that is attempting to align elements to the bottom in the bootstrap 4 doc?

Comment: I mean I tried everything on their page, and nothing worked. I could have left those attempts as well.

Comment: Toskan, I'm asking you where _**your**_ code is that's attempting to align elements at the bottom.

Comment: no need to get upset.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment
I am trying to use the bootstrap 4 classes to align the elements to the bottom. Respectively justify content between the elements

Comment: Can you please provide a diagram of the desired layout? Without a `.col-**-**` class your divs are going to be 100% width which means they'll end up stacking.

Comment: I added a picture of what I really want (but using flex and bootstrap) I added as well a link I just found to some bootstrap utilities

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#with-align-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.row` needs to be full height too. You can use the `h-100` class for `height:100%`

https://www.codeply.com/go/EA6zTlQLxC

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col my-top">
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col my-bot align-self-end">
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      grey stuff in between. no hard coding with padding or such allowed
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am surprised it works man... because I was there already I think... you can remove `justify-content-between` btw. It is not needed for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**flexbox**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) and [**sizing**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/sizing/) classes.

Make sure the containing element is the full height of the parent (here I'm assuming it's the height of the viewport). When using `height: 100%;` you'll have to apply `height: 100%;` from the root (`html`) down through each element to the target element `.flex-column`. If you don't the the `.flex-column` element will only be as tall as it's content and can't stretch out to provide a space.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: gray;
}

.my-top {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.my-bot {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-end flex-column">
    <div class="w-100 my-top">
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
      <p>Red container to the top (works)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 mt-auto my-bot">
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      <p>Blue container to the bottom (doesn't work)</p>
      grey stuff in between. no hard coding with padding or such allowed
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: Make sure to use **Full Screen** option when viewing the code snippet.*

Comment: the thing is, height doesn't help me really. I need min-height. Height needs to be auto to allow overflowing of content or for small screens

Comment: The only `.h-100` that I see that you would want to change to accommodate that is the one shared with `.container`. For that just do what you did before, `.container { min-height: 100%; }`.